# Understanding/Deriving the compound interest formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, finance

We have the following formula when working with interest rates:
$$FV\:=\:PV\cdot\left(1+\frac r{100\,k}\right)^{kn}$$
where $FV$ = future value, $PV$ = present value, $n$ is the number of years, $k$ is the number of compounding periods a year, and $r$ in % is the nominal annual rate of interest.

Now, I could, technically, just apply this formula blindly. But I prefer to understand things and, if nothing else, feel that this will help me understand it better. Therefore:

Could anyone please explain intuitively where this formula comes from? Why are we dividing $r$ by $k$ and then raising to the power of $k$? Why not just multiply $PV$ by $(1+\frac r{100})^{n}$?

I suppose this has something to do with the fact that $r$ is a **nominal** annual interest rate, but then why not just state the 'correct' annual interest rate to begin with... an example of this is in the first answer below when we discuss a 20% nominal interest rate.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to start the 100 is just a way to convert the percentage value and isn't really necessary as percentages are typically understood to be decimals anyway.

So now we're left with
$$FV = PV\left(1+\frac{r}{k}\right)^{kn}$$

The intuition here is quite simple, you're just considering '$k$' extra periods per year at '$\frac{1}{k}$'th of the rate. for example instead of an interest rate of $10\%$ per annum for $10$ years we can think of it as $5\%$ per 'half year' with twice as many half years ($20$ half years).

So now we're back down to trying to understand:

$$FV = PV\left(1+r\right)^n$$

Which is simply just stating that the future value of an investment (or loan or whatever else you're compounding) is its present value, iteratively multiplied (n times) by some factor $(1+r)$. And this is just the way we increase a value by a percentage. For example if I wanted to increase $100$ by $20\%$ I would say $100\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)$ which is equal to $120$. If I wanted it to grow twice, I would multiply it again so:

$$100\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)$$

or, equivalently: $100\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)^2$

If I wanted to grow it n times, I would say:

$$100\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)\cdot...\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)\qquad\text{'n' times}$$

or, equivalently: $100\cdot\left(1+20\%\right)^n$

Bringing this idea back to the original formula you shared, if I changed the context to compounding $\$100$ at $20\%$ per annum for $n$ years, but I wanted to compound it every $6$ months ($2$ times a year) I would essentially split my $20\%$ rate in half and compound it twice as many times:

$$100\cdot\left(1+\frac{20\%}{2}\right)^{2n}$$

Where here $k$ from the original formula is $2$.

It is important to understand that this is different from taking the yearly rate and raising it to the power of the number of years because of the nature of compound interest. Every time an investment is compounded, it's growing by it's current value as opposed to growing by it's initial value (like in simple interest) So in the scenario above, compounding it twice a year means that it can grow for the first half of the year and then the next half grows from whatever value the investment had at the half way point (which for positive interest rates will be more than the initial value) so it grows faster. The more compounding periods we have, the greater the $FV$ will be if everything else remains constant (to a limit: if you want to learn more about this limit you can research the number $e$).

$\textbf{Important for building intuition}$

If you want to visualise, this hop onto desmos, or any other graphing website/software, and type in: $y=a(1+\frac{r}{x})^{xn}$ into one line, and $y=a(1+r)^n$ on another. You can set values yourself for present value (a), rate (r) and number of periods (n) or you can just add a slider for them and experiment a little bit!

You should be able to see that when $x>1$, i.e. we're compounding more frequently than once per year, the formula with compounding is greater than the formula without.

Just for fun, while you're on Desmos, type in $y=ae^{rn}$ in another line and you'll see that the compounding function approaches $e$ but never surpasses it - that's what I was referencing earlier on when I mentioned a limit.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Some of the basic stuff about interest rates that you have included are very simple indeed so I get all of that! A few follow ups: You talk about a nominal interest rate of 20% per annum compounded biannually...but then why do we state the nominal interest rate to be 20% per annum. Why not just give it as 21% which is what 10% compounded twice is? This is what I don't understand...from an intuition POV.

Comment: Also, this statement:  The more compounding periods we have, the greater the 
will be if everything else remains constant (to a limit: if you want to learn more about this limit you can research the number  - please could you give more details? Surely if we have more and more compound periods then the value of an investment has to increase because that is what interest is? Why is it that it tends towards a limit?

Comment: =(1+/)^() - in this formula, is (x) is the number of compounding periods and n the number of years or vice versa? I think you mention it as (n) by accident at first but then use x correctly?

Comment: You could use the $21\%$ but this is equivalent to what's already in the formula. The way you would compute that is by using the factor in the formula already - I think you get it, but are maybe not seeing how you're doing the exact same thing?

Comment: As for the limit question, I'm not sure if this is in the scope of what you're doing but it's interesting nevertheless. You are right, it is true that the more you compound the more the value of the investment increases - but it does this at a decreasing rate. You can try this with a simpler example: say $PV = \$1, r = 100\%$ per annum for one year and try different compounding periods.
$k = 1 \implies FV = 2$ ...
$k = 2 \implies FV = 2.25$ (a benefit of 0.25) ...
$k = 3 \implies FV = 2.37$ (a benefit of 0.12) ...
$k = 4 \implies FV = 2.44$ (a benefit of 0.07) ...

Comment: Keep going with this pattern and you'll notice that this number approaches the value $e \approx 2.71828...$. For example sub in $k = 10000$ so you have $1(1+\frac{1}{10000})^{10000} = 2.71815$. That's all the limit implies. So while it increases infinitely, the amount it increases by becomes smaller and smaller and you never end up being able to surpass the limit of $e$.

Comment: And yes, $x$ is the number of compounding periods and $n$ is the number of 'years' (although it can just as easily be a different unit depending on context). Graphing this allows you to see that as $x$ (again, compounding periods) increases, the $FV$ flattens out to a certain value asymptotically.

Also, feel free to keep asking questions, but if this has been helpful can you accept my answer?

Comment: Thanks @Kurtooso, I understand everything now...except for the thing about 21%...if that is equivalent to what the formula states, then what is the significance of a 'nominal interest rate of 20%' - why even have a NOMINAL interest rate...what is the advantage? Why not just state the REAL interest rate?

Comment: And yes, of course, sorry, I will accept your answer, it has been very useful.

Comment: I think there's some confusion regarding your use of "real interest rate". As I understand, real interest rate takes into consideration inflation and isn't relevant here. There is terminology that tends to be used here which you can see more of here: https://www.csun.edu/~ghe59995/docs/Interpreting%20Nominal%20&%20Effective%20Interest%20Rates.pdf (don't worry, it's only 3 pages and 2 of them are just a tables)

Comment: And it's mainly just a question of what's happening in real life. Your bank for example might offer you $10\%$ per annum returns on your savings compounded quarterly (this is obviously not realistic, just a nice round number). so you could say this is equivalent to $\left(1+\frac{0.1}{4}\right)^4-1 = 10.3812890625...\%$. This might be useful to know, but it's not really explaining what's happening in reality as it doesn't do a good job of describing that you're actually making $2.5\%$ every 3 months (which is when they would pay you that interest). It's also a very yucky number.

Comment: thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what i dont understand from your initial explanation is how both FV=PV(1+r)^n and FV=PV(1+r/k)^kn are used to calculate annual interest rate increases , say if we had a standard annual rate of 20% splitting this in 2 such 10 percent is compounded in the first of the year and then another 10 percent in the second half of the year , will not give the same value if I were to just compound 20% ex r=0.2 n=9 k=12 (monthly compounds),PV = 42 if I were to use these values in both equations , I would give different results , so which one would be correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Dividing $r$ by $k$ takes the compounding frequency into account. If you don't divide by $k$, you end up applying your interest rate $r$ $k$ times per year instead of applying your interest rate $r$ in $k$ installments of $\frac{r}{k}$ per year. In other words, if I have a $20 \%$ interest rate compounded monthly, failing to divide by $k$ gives me $20 \%$ interest $12$ times per year (i.e. $240 \%$ interest compounded monthly) rather than $\frac{20 \%}{12} \approx 1.67 \%$ interest $12$ times per year (i.e. $20 \%$ interest compounded monthly).

Raising to the power of $k$ ensures that you apply the interest with the desired compounding frequency. $n$ is in years; if you don't adjust the exponent you will be earning  $\frac{r}{k}$ percent interest once per year rather than $\frac{r}{k}$ percent interest $k$ times per year. In other words, if I have a $20 \%$ interest rate compounded monthly, failing to raise to the power of $k$ gives me $\frac{20 \%}{12} \approx 1.67 \%$ interest per year rather than $20 \%$ interest per year. You couldn't just let $n=12$ instead of applying a factor $k$: that would mean that your compounding period is $12$ **years** rather than $12$ months.

Comment: what i dont understand is if the compound installments are given every month in ur example doing FV=PV(1+0.2/12)^12n would give a different result as opposed to doing FV=PV(1+0.2)^n , the former way cannot be described as giving 20% interest annually as you can clearly see with the numerical examples that the percentage change wouldn't be 20 %